# Use methods directly that back spring security's built-in expressions

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'd like to use some (Java) methods in my controllers that are similiar to the [built-in expressions provided by Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) e.g. hasRole([role]) or isFullyAuthenticated().

Do you know where I can find these methods and how to call them within a Java method of a controller (I don't want to use Spring EL, I want to use plain Java)? E.g something like

```
SomeStaticSpringSecutityClass.isFullyAuthenticated();
```

EDIT:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()
```

Actually doesn't really work. This method also returns true if the user is authenticated as "Anonymous". See the link to the spring security docs from above:

> isAuthenticated() Returns true if the user is not anonymous

Instead you have to use something like that:

```
public boolean isAuthenticated() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return !(authentication == null || authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken);
}
```

But anyway: I don't really want to implement logic again, that is already implemented somewhere in Spring Security. Additionally

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

does not provided methods like isFullyAuthenticated() or hasRole().

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [org.springframework.security.core.contex.SecurityContextHolder](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html). For instance to check if the current user is authenticated:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated()
```

Comment: handle it carefully, it would be true for anonymous user

Answer (score 0):

I found the `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter` that use the interface:

```
AuthenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(Authentication authentication);
```

If you want to use the Spring source code, you can check the class `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` that instantiates this interfaces as below:

```
private final AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

public Authentication getAuthentication() {
    if (!authenticationTrustResolver.isAnonymous(auth)) {
        return auth;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I looked into documentation and I didn't find a utility class to do it.